# Iteration through JSON dependent on asynchronous calls

Tags: javascript, json, asynchronous, promise, geojson

I'm trying to create a promise function that will iterate through a geoJSON object, using one URL-esque property stored alongside a placeholder value property to call for the data stored at that address. The JSON iteration itself is functional, but I can't seem to get the main promise to time properly, it's returning resolved before my values are actually brought in.

```
    //Here is one feature in my geoJSON object
    {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "name": "AC4",
      "url": "/*Removed*/",
      "values": {
        "DA_T": {
          "ORD": "station:|slot:/Drivers/NiagaraNetwork/S_1563/B_1964/B1964_SSC2/points/AC4/MixedAirTemp",
          "value": "placeholder",
        }
      }
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Polygon",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          [102.0,-59.0],
          [102.0,-73.5],
          [67.5,-73.5],
          [67.5,-59.0]
        ]
      ]
    }},



  //This is what I currently have for my iterating function
  function jsonValueFill(json, valueName) {
    return new Promise (function(resolve, reject){
      var i = 0;
      var k = json.features.length;
      while (i<k) {
        console.log('iteration: ' + i)
        if (json.features[i].properties.values.valueName != undefined){
          numFromPoint (json.features[i].properties.values.valueName.ORD)
          .then(function(output){
            json.features[i].properties.values.valueName.value = output
          });
        };
      i++;
      if(i == k) {resolve(json)}
      }
    })
  };
```

numFromPoint is a promise function I created to pull a value from an internal address called an ORD, and I've confirmed that it works as expected. However, even adding a setTimeout(function(){console.log(testJson)}, 6000) to check the state of the object well after I iterate through the object, the value property isn't being set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it can be simpler:

```
function jsonValueFill(json, valueName) {
  const promises = json.features.map(feature => {
    if (feature.properties.values[valueName] !== undefined) {
      return numFromPoint(feature.properties.values[valueName].ORD)
        .then(function(output) {
          feature.properties.values[valueName].value = output
        })
    }
  })

  return Promise.all(promises).then(() => json)
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, you're a lifesaver! Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
while (i<k) {
    console.log('iteration: ' + i)
    if (json.features[i].properties.values.valueName != undefined){
      numFromPoint (json.features[i].properties.values.valueName.ORD)
      .then(function(output){
        json.features[i].properties.values.valueName.value = output
      });
    };
  i++;
```

See in this piece of code, the value of i when numFromPoint resolves is different than when it started. Calling a promise in a loop is not a good idea either. Abstract this out in a closure.

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense, thank you! I'm still not entirely used to the quirks of async javascript, I keep missing small things like this